# storing email from gmail and presenting in front end

Tags: database, python

I'm looking for recommendation as to the best approach to take for creating a dashboard front end system for a client.

Essentially, the client would like to automate how they look at their emails, and based on certain data from a specific email, they want to see this information on a front end system. Right now the client checks their email for receipts, but would like to automate this.

My approach was to create a python script that would go to the email after X period of time, save the parsed content to a database, and make this information available on a front end view using PHP / javascript.

Maybe there is a better approach or another software that is capable of one of these steps ?

Comment: The client doesn’t know it yet, but they will want to reply to email directly from your front end, using their Gmail address *and* possibly/probably their Gmail contacts. Clarify this before you start, as it ***will*** have consequences. Btw, do they use browser based Gmail or a desktop client like Outlook, Thunderbird, etc?

Comment: Where does your Python run? Client side, I guess. Why bother with any server side (PHP)? You could keep I tall client side, using SQLite as your database, and also use Python for your GUI (for Window's based RAD, I like Lazarus)